# Record mac screen + audio + skype call?

Tags: mac, screen, recording

my friend and I are planning to make minecraft gameplays, but each one from home, so what software I need, I know quicktime records the screen but I need also the recording from the skype call... Please help.

Comment: A free and **open source** solution is to use [Open Broadcasting Software](https://obsproject.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose to record using the quicktime player if you also have sound flower installed, this will record any application audio (you would have to test to see if if captures both the incoming and outgoing sounds via Skype)

You can find Soundflower [here](https://rogueamoeba.com/freebies/soundflower/).

When installed start a screen recording in quicktime then click on the down arrow as seen below and choose Soundflower

[image]

There are a number of paid applications that will do sound and screen recording if you want more control :-

iShowu -- http://www.shinywhitebox.com/ishowu

Camptasia  -- http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia.html

Voila -- http://www.globaldelight.com/voila/

Answer (score 1):

Yeap! Quicktime player is enough to record Mac screen and audio. And for recording Skype Call, you may try [Call Recorder](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/callrecorder/) or [Apowersoft Mac Screen Recorder](http://www.apowersoft.com/mac-os-screen-recorder).These two are what I have used for recording RTS games like Dota. They are not free but work well, and have many options like converting and sharing. Anyway, worth a try.